# R data.table Join On complex condition

Tags: r, data.table

I know that with R `data.table`s, you can do something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.id1 = t2.id2
```

Like so:

```
t1[t2, on = c(id1 = "id2")]
```

but how would you do something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.text LIKE CONCAT('%', t2.text, '%')
```

in `data.table`?

Comment: Are `%` supposed to be literal percent signs or do you just want to add arbitrary text to the column specification in t2? If the former, can't you just rename the column?

Comment: Sorry, the `=` was supposed to be a `LIKE`

Comment: Ok, so quickly reviewing SQL you want to be able to join on t2.text even if it has characters on either side? Is this just because you don't know what the right id column is called in t2?

Comment: no, I know what it's called. Say `t1.text` is `'ABC'` and `t2.text` is `abc (ABC)`. I want it to join together using the LIKE keyword. The first case is easy since I just match one key equaling another, but for the second case, I'd need a `grepl` or something.

Comment: ok, well if you know what the column name in t2 is that you want to join on you can use the solution I just posted